# PHPMailer won't send

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm pretty new to programming and I'm using MAMP (with PHP7.0.0) on my iMac for development. I need to send out emails to confirm customer registration. For testing purposes I just want to use my standard GMail account to send an email from myself to myself. I have tried PHP's native mail() function but that doesn't work and I suspect that's because GMail uses some kind of special authentication.

So I've downloaded PHPMailer (5.2.13). I'm not quite sure how to use Composer for autoloading so I've simply downloaded the following files to my project top folder:

`class.phpmailer.php`,
`class.pop3.php`,
`class.smtp.php` and
`class.phpmaileroauthgoogle.php`

and I've included them thus at the top of my php test page:

```
require_once "./class.phpmailer.php";
require_once "./class.pop3.php";
require_once "./class.smtp.php";
require_once "./class.phpmaileroauthgoogle.php";
```

The rest of the test code is taken from the PHPMailer ReadMe example:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP(); 
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                            
$mail->Username = 'myUsername@gmail.com';  
$mail->Password = 'myPassword';  
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->setFrom('myUsername@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('myUsername@gmail.com', 'Recipient');
$mail->isHTML(true); 
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->Subject = 'Test email';
$mail->Body = 'Test message';
if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

My code hangs when it gets to the `if(!$mail->send()) {` line.

I'm not getting any PHP errors in my log file but the PHP code (which is called via a JQuery call in a JS script from a test page) is clearly halting and not returning to the JS script.

Am I missing any PHPMailer files? Have I got a syntax error? Do I need to use OAuth2 code and, if so, how do I set that up? Should I get another (non-GMail) account for testing? Any thoughts please for a beginner?

Comment: in order for `mail()` to work, you need to have a local SMTP mailer, you'd have a much easier time using something like the gmail API on local

Comment: you can use the debug output: $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';`` - for a simple test script use [https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps)

Comment: Also read the docs in the project wiki, linked from the readme.

Answer (score 0):

```
require("./class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->IsMail();
$mail->setFrom('myUsername@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('myUsername@gmail.com', 'Recipient');
$mail->isHTML(true); 
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->Subject = 'Test email';
$mail->Body = 'Test message';
if(!$mail->send()) {
echo 'Message could not be sent.';
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Try to see if that gives any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have had problems with sending email to and from the same email address. Some servers deem that a invalid/unwanted msg and will not accept it returning a error that usually is intercepted by a catchall default error test coding structure  in the php files.Just a thought Hope it helps.